# signinwithemailandpassword failed: First argument "email" must be a valid string

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-redux

[App loads and Authentication form shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZdsd.png)
[android emulator showing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VgB2.png)

Hi , so i'm a newbie to React and i'm following this Udemy course .. when i try to run, my app is loaded and it renders the Authentication form like a charm with no errors or warnings.

but once i try to sign in , once i hit the **Login button** : the scary Red Screen pops up .

i went through all the similar subjects , but none of them seem to fix my error .. i cant even get what exactly is wrong here

Here's my LoginForm.js :

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Card, CardSection, Input, Button } from './common';
import { emailChanged, passwordChanged, loginUser } from '../actions';


class LoginForm extends Component {
    onEmailChange(text) {
        this.props.emailChanged(text);
    }


    onPasswordChange(text) {
        this.props.passwordChanged(text);
    }
    onButtonPress() {
        const { email, password } = this.props;

        this.props.loginUser({ email, password });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Card>
                <CardSection>
                    <Input
                     label="Email"
                     placeholder="votre email ici"
                     onChangeText={this.onEmailChange.bind(this)}
                     value={this.props.email}  
                    /> 
                </CardSection>

                <CardSection>
                    <Input 
                      secureTextEntry
                      label="mot de passe"
                      placeholder="mot de passe"
                      onChangeText={this.onPasswordChange.bind(this)}
                      value={this.props.password}
                    />    
                </CardSection>

                <CardSection>
                    <Button onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}>
                        Login                    
                    </Button>                    
                </CardSection>
            </Card>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        email: state.auth.email,
        password: state.auth.password 
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { emailChanged, passwordChanged, 
loginUser })(LoginForm);
```

Here's my actions creator :

```
import firebase from 'firebase';

import { 
    EMAIL_CHANGED,
    PASSWORD_CHANGED,
    LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS 
} from './types';

export const emailChanged = (text) => {
    return {
        type: EMAIL_CHANGED,
        paymoad: text
    };
};

export const passwordChanged = (text) => {
    return {
        type: PASSWORD_CHANGED,
        payload: text
    };
};

export const loginUser = ({ email, password }) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(user => {
            dispatch({ type: LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS, payload: user });
    });
    };
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `emailChanged action`, you are using the wrong key for the payload. Instead of using `payload` you are using `paymoad`

With this you are not updating the store and the value for the email is not valid.

Comment: If that works, could you accept the answer, please :)

Comment: i'm a new user , so i cant vote on answers yet .. and tbh , i cant find any other option on how to ACCEPT the answer .. please tell me if i'm missing something here . 

Cordially

Comment: @Rafael Motta  I have the same issue, even I have written payload in the emailChanged action. Please suggest if there is anything.